# Approximation to a composite function near 0 and order of remainder

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, approximation

Consider a composite function $f(g(x))$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. We want to approach this function for $x\rightarrow0$, and we suppose that near $0$ we have $g(x)=\mathcal{O}(g_0(x))$ for some function $g_0$. In fact:
$$\tag{1}\frac{g(x)}{g_0(x)}=1+\alpha x=1+\mathcal{O}(x)$$
for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Assume further that:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)=+\infty,\qquad \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\beta$$
for some $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Under which conditions can we make the approximation $f(g(x))=\mathcal{O}(f(g_0(x)))$ near $0$?**

**What can I deduce from $(1)$ in relation to the order of the remainder from the approximation $f(g_0(x))$ $-$ if anything?** In particular can we write that:
$$f(g(x))=f(g_0(x))+\mathcal{O}(x)$$

Comment: $\lim_0f\circ g=\eta=\lim_0f\circ g_0$ hence $f(g(x))=\mathcal{O}(f(g_0(x)))$ near $0$ indeed provided $\beta\ne0,$ but you can say nothing more since you don't know the rate of convergence for $f.$